# How To create Licence File with Hash for verification

Tags: hash, licensing, license-key

I need to create Licence file with Hash like in this example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTD5m.png

when any character in the file is changed or added the license file will not be accepted.

thanks :*

Comment: You have to ask a more specific question. This is way too broad to be a good fit for stackoverflow. It's also unclear.

Answer (score 0):

### Okay I need to create a licence file with string data like this:

```
users: .inf

:shards: 1

:collectors:

:collectors: 3

  :anonymizers: 9

:nia:

- 2

- true

:exploits: true

:gapi: 100

:rmi:

- true

- true

:alerting: true

:ocr: true

:profiling: true

:intelligence: true

:archive: 0

:connectors: true

:translation: false

:hostname_sync: false

:modify: true

:deletion: false

:check: 3OqZ1N5a

:digest_enc: true
***
and at the end of file i need to generate Hash like this :

***
:crc: $2a$10$rQULDKlViK8zQmFe2F1rT.dw.dXaG5f6mU7EerC188SBsp3t2IGz6

:sha1: 80987d0c145eb5a71294fce8306761aa36e4820318b7125e8f1ab66a42375b13

:digest: fb11b44a95a6cbce1b7d61294b827276fb1f1a70

:signature: 23235187453c677cba17d1f0b7c2a54b6c2f6ade8b9e8abdcea389d07873583e

:integrity: 34e4a6e23ea4bf8a4b5bc50d03bae5966a3ccd531bf31ac51e0c1dcebec5af7f77bd69f99521b17cf1eb344372b65d3a
```

---

to check if any change in value in the strings